# How to determine Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word._Document is closed or not using C#.net

Tags: c#, .net, office-automation

I am using the `Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word._Document` to open and update the word document using c#.net code, every thing works fine except I am unable to determine the property in object of `Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word._Document` that can give the status weather denouement is closed or not in some point of code execution.
following is the sample code that I am doing to determine to close the document if it is open.

```
    public void UpdateSendDocument(string docPath)
    {

        bool docIsOpen = false;
        Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word._Document wordDocumentBase = null;
        Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.Application officeWordApplication = null;
        try
        {
            officeWordApplication = new Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.Application();
            wordDocumentBase = officeWordApplication.Documents.Open(docPath, Format: Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.WdPasteOptions.wdKeepSourceFormatting);
            docIsOpen = true;

            // Update the document 
            // ApplyChanges(wordDocumentBase);

            wordDocumentBase.Close();
            docIsOpen = false;

            // SendToNewParty(docPath);

        }
        finally
        {
            //here I wand to know the any property or method available in wordDocumentBase to check weather denouement is still open or not 
            if (wordDocumentBase != null && docIsOpen)
            {
                wordDocumentBase.Close(Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing);
            }
            Marshal.ReleaseComObject(wordDocumentBase);
            wordDocumentBase = null;

            if (officeWordApplication != null)
            {
                officeWordApplication.Quit(Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing);
                Marshal.ReleaseComObject(officeWordApplication);
                officeWordApplication = null;
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Why do you care if it is still open? Can't you just try to close it anyway and catch the exception?

Comment: @briantyler if it is already closed and and try close again, it throws the exception that I don't want if it can be avoided by using right property to check the status open/closed before closing the document.

Comment: In my opinion the right way is to attempt the close and catch the exception, rethrowing if it isn't the one you expected.

Comment: yes, @briantyler this is only a trick to do it right now as there is no method available to determine the state.

Comment: Did you find a suitable method?

Comment: @MarianV., no I use same as briantyler suggested above